# How to make an alias in the url of asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

This is my URL web site : "www.mysite.com". If I want to log in to have an administrator lever, I have to go : "www.mysite.com/Account/LogOn".

Can everyone can tell me, how can I use only "www.mysite.com/administrator" to log in to administrator level of my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Authorize attribute on your Index action in the Administrator controller so if someone goes to /Admininistrator/Index or /Administrator then they wil be redirected to the the logon page and then once logged in back to the admin page.

Comment: Do you mean, I have to modify my Action name?

Comment: No, you must use the [Authorize] attribute. Check out http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/09/CustomAuthorizationASPNETMVCFrameworkAuthorizeAttribute.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is to the `RouteCollection.MapRoute()` method to define your custom route.  Something like this would suffice:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin", // Route name
    "Administrator", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

What this does is translates `www.mysite.com/adminsistrator` to your `Account` controller with the `LogOn` action.

Comment: Can you tell me, where can I put this block of code in my project?

Comment: You put this in your Application_Start() method in your global.asax file.   There should be the default route already there, so add the code below that.

Comment: It error when I put that (Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.). This is my Application_Start(): `protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

               routes.MapRoute(
              "Admin", // Route name
              "Administrator", // URL with parameters
              new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn" } // Parameter defaults
              );

            
        }`

Comment: Put it in your RegisterRoutes() method. "routes" is not the class.

Comment: Anyone know about that problems? Thanks.